# Question on efficient/correct data structure for 2D array computations in python

Tags: python, numpy, data-structures

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the most efficient (read: quickest) way to iteratively make changes to a 2D numpy array, as well as being able to track the changes made to this array.

In my particular problem, I'm trying to change the elements of my 2D array like so:

```
import numpy as np

a1 = np.array([   [2, 1, 4, 2],
                  [1, 2, 3, 3], 
                  [1, 2, 1, 1],
                  [2, 3, 5, 6]
              ])

new_arrays1 = []

for i in range(0, a1.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0, a1.shape[1] - 1):
        a1_move = np.copy(a1)
        a1_move[i, j], a1_move[i, j + 1] = a1_move[i, j + 1], a1_move[i, j]
        new_arrays1.append(a1_move)

new_arrays2 = []

for a2 in new_arrays1:
    for i in range(0, a2.shape[0]):
        for j in range(0, a2.shape[1] - 1):
            a2_move = np.copy(a2)
            a2_move[i, j], a2_move[i, j + 1] = a2_move[i, j + 1], a2_move[i, j]
            new_arrays2.append(a2_move)
```

That is, I move all possible elements in each row of the 2D array `a1` one-by-one and create 12 (4x4) new arrays. Then, I move all possible elements in each row of each of the new 12 arrays to create 12x12 = 144 new arrays in total.

My question hereby is: is there any data structure / technique / something that will allow me to know what steps I have taken (moves of the arrays) to reach the final 144 arrays? I understand that for the above example,  the matrix `new_arrays[0]` leads to all matrices `new_arrays2[0:11]`. However, I would like to know the moves taken to reach the arrays in `new_arrays2[0:11]` as well.

In my full code, the initial array (`a1`) is 12x6. Additionally, I need to perform these operations on the matrices more than twice, most likely 4-5 times in total (which means 60^4 or 60^5 total matrices to analyze), which means that I need an efficient solution to solve this.

My end-goal is to analyze all the arrays in the final step (which is at step 2 in the example above), deduce which array is "best", and use the movements made to the initial array to reach this "best" array in my code.

Comment: Maybe you should look at the notation used by mathematicians in Group Theory.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for the suggestion. How is this fruitful towards steering me in the right direction though?

Comment: They use efficient notation for representing how sequences are permuted.

Comment: @Barmar Noted, thanks.

Comment: I think this is off-topic for Stack Overflow. See: [help/on-topic].

Comment: @AMC Where would you put it?

Comment: @MennoVanDijk I really don't know, currently it's probably too broad/vague for most forums. Can you share far more information/context for this?